# What contributes to the energy cost of multistage compression at high discharge pressures?

Tags: gas, compressors, compressed-gases

I'm getting into hydrogen compression from a theoretical point of view and am looking for a model to describe the energy requirements.

I've gathered, that hydrogen is often compressed with piston compressors and that a standard way to model these, seems to be to treat the compression as fully isentropic and then account for the failure of this by multiplying with an "isentropic efficiency" $\eta_{\text{is}}$. Meaning, I can compute the difference of the specific enthalpy $h$ of the gas before and after compression and multiply with the isentropic efficiency:

$W_s = \frac{1}{\eta_{\text{is}}(p_{out},p_{\text{in}})}(h(p_{out}, T_{out}) - h(p_{in}, T_{in})) $.

Additionally hydrogen (and other gases) heats up tremendously under compression and therefore the ratio of pressures usually fulfills $ \frac{p_{out}}{p_{in}} \leq 5$ to keep the compressor cool enough. To deal with this, compression is done in multiple stages and in between the gas is cooled back to acceptable temperatures.

If I introduce some simplifications I can compute the power demand of a multistage compressor.
Assumptions:

1. The intercoolers cool back to the initial temperature.
2. The energy requirements of the intercoolers are small and can be neglected.
3. The pressure drop in the intercoolers can be neglected.
4. The isentropic efficiency is equal for all stages and constant for a compressor.

With these assumptions the total specific work can be by adding the single stage specific works. Using

$r_{\text{total}} = \frac{p_{out}}{p_{in}}$

$r = r_{\text{total}}^{\frac{1}{n}}$

where $n$ is the number of stage, we add together $n$ specific works, each from $r^kp_{in}$ to $r^{k+1}p_{in}$, where $k = 0\dots n-1$.

If I take a look at compressing to moderately high pressures (maybe 250 bar), this model makes predictions well in line with literature.
For high pressures, from 300 bar to 1000 bar, these two sources predict different needed specific works that are much higher than the model above predicts, if I choose an isentropic efficiency that is in agreement at lower pressures.
[Dumas,2011](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257333806_Effects_of_Altitude_on_Photovoltaic_Production_of_hydrogen)
[Irena-report](https://www.irena.org/-/media/Files/IRENA/Agency/Publication/2020/Dec/IRENA_Green_hydrogen_cost_2020.pdf)

Is there an important step missing in the model above, that explains higher energy usage at higher pressures? Should I distrust the sources?
I'm at a loss. Please enlighten me.

If you have isentropic efficiencies for hydrogen compressors and/or even energy profiles of intercoolers, that would help me tremendously!

Comment: Interesting. AFAIK piston compressors are usually modeled as adiabatic. Do you know why way you describe is chosen?

Comment: My approach is just the chaining of adiabatic compression in each stage. In order to compute the enthalpy of the outgoing gas, I need the entropy to stay the same, so I use isentropic compression. This approach is detailed in "Smith: Chemical Process, Design and Integration", https://www.amazon.com/Chemical-Process-Integration-Robin-Smith/dp/0471486817